# Do you have time available in the week or two to come?

Tags: american-english

My client is asking me the following question:

> "Do you have time available in the week or two to come?".

What does this mean? We are from different countries and I am freelancing. He needs me to do some work for him. So does this mean **after** 1,2 weeks or I supposed to work **within** next two weeks? I hope I explained it right.

Comment: In your context, ***a week or two*** means ***a very small number of weeks** [probably only one or two]*. The client would probably think it was perfectly reasonable for you to respond by saying *No problem - I have two days available starting 15 days from now,* even though technically speaking this would be outside the *literally* requested time-frame.

Comment: In this case, in = within.  *In the (time-period) to come* is another way of saying "during the next (time-period)".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In American English as commonly used, this would most likely mean within (during) the next two weeks.

Two elements decide the issue for me. The first is the definite article *the*, which is not used to indicate a generic amount of time but rather a specific period of time. The second is the phrase "to come", which would be an odd construction to use if he specifically wanted the work to begin after that time.

Consider the following as answers to the question "When should we meet?":

> Let's meet in a week.

This means that we will meet after a week has passed.

> Let's meet in the coming week.

This means that we will meet during a particular week.

Answer (score 1):

This means **within** the next two weeks.